# How to retrieve a file sent over IPFS with its extension?

Tags: python, http, upload, client, ipfs

I am sharing some files over IPFS and I would like to retrieve the file extensions as well when downloading the files by their CID. I am using the following code:

```
import ipfshttpclient

# Connect to the IPFS daemon
client = ipfshttpclient.connect()


def share_file(filepath):
    # Add the file to IPFS
    res = client.add(filepath)
    ipfs_hash = res["Hash"]
    print("IPFS hash is ", ipfs_hash,"Name ",res["Name"])
    return ipfs_hash


ipfs_hash = share_file("DSC00001.jpg")
client.get(ipfs_hash, "download_jpg_file")
```

The code is uploading the jpg file to the IPFS network and then downloading it in the download_jpg_file folder. How can I also retrieve the extension-".jpg" when downloading the file? So far, the file is saved by the CID (hash ID) of the upload-> the file will have the name `QmPLLLfBJ1yBMAMWVFzYGSHzGrQ1zUqMG4CLKNqCS2DEnD`  for example. I want to also store the extensions of the files so that I can open them without the need to specify on the open what program to use to open the files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are retrieving via HTTP gateway, you can attach [`?filename=cat.jpg` parameter](https://specs.ipfs.tech/http-gateways/path-gateway/#filename-request-query-parameter) to the URL, and that will produce a response with `Content-Disposition` header you are looking for.

Otherwise, you need to modify your code to save retrieved bytes in a file that has the correct extension.

If you are retrieving data published by a third party, and you don't know what is the content type, you need to do mime type sniffing, a library you could use is [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type).

Answer (score -1):

You best shot is probably checking the "Content-Type" header from the response.